# Mixing MVC 5.0 with WebAPI 2.0

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

We are migrating an application from classic asp to .NET and we have decided to use webAPI 2.0 with MVC framework 5.0 and I am pretty new to these frameworks. We have done lots of research and came up with the following scenario's

Scenario 1

1) While Saving a screen we are going to call the webAPI(since it will take care of serializations to the models).
2) While Getting the data we are going to use MVC as renders a view.

Scenario 2

1) Write Web API for both Save and Get the data from the database.
2) Use MVC and call the web API for both save and Get the data.

Scenario 3
1) Use MVC alone to get the data and write the data to the database. (As of now we are not exposing the webAPI it is for internal use only and none other applications needs these calls)

Scenario 4 
1) Write a Web API and call it from Jquery.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Thanks